# Android JSON fetching - No value for (value) eventhough the value exists

Tags: android, json

I have a valid json link, and I want to fetch data from it.

This is my code, for fetching data:

```
try {
        JSONObject topicsObject = new JSONObject(getTopicsJSON);
        JSONArray topics = topicsObject.getJSONArray("Topics");

        for (int i = 0; i<topics.length();i++){

            SuperTrenerTopic stt = new SuperTrenerTopic();
            JSONObject sub_topic = topics.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject topic = sub_topic.getJSONObject("Topic");
        ...
    }
```

On the last line of code, I get ann error saying org.json.JSONException: No value for Topic.

Following screenshot shows that it is not correct, as I Log-ed the recieved JSON, and you can clearly see that in fact, there IS a "Topic" object out there:

[image]

First Log represents the first part of an entire Json responce, and the second one is the Topic object itself.
Here is another screenshot of the JSON format i took from my browser:

[image]

You can notice that "Topic" and "meta" objects are on the same hierarchy level.
I fetch "meta" object with no problem whatsoever, using the same code I would use for fetching 'Topics", but for some reason, fetching "Topics" doesn't work out.

here is the code I successfully use to fetch "meta' object:

```
JSONObject meta = sub_topic.getJSONObject("meta");
```

**What could be the cause of this?
Is there something realy obvious that I'm missing out?**

Comment: Try printing the sub_topic object when you get it and see if it is what you expect. Also, is it failing on the first topic? or somewhere further along the iteration? Maybe part of your JSON string is malformed.

Comment: I would feel better if the JSON was malformed, but that's not the case. I made a native iOS app, and now im making native Android, using the same json..and it works on iOS.
Also, I printed out sub_topic, it's printed out as expected, and you can see on the screenshot i posted that "Topic" object is there where it should be.
Im suspecting this is one of those random android studio features, where something simply doesn't work, and you have to delete an entire class, and start over again...